# Load JQGrid from another site

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, httphandler

I have a JQGrid on site A and it is loaded in user control.  I have a handler on site B to load the control.  Site B returns JSON {"rows":[{"CategoryName":"Beverages"}]} but JQGrid will not load it.

Any ideas??

$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
 url: 'https://SITEB.com/ReviewHandler.ashx',
datatype: "json",
colModel: [{ label: 'CategoryName', name: 'CategoryName', width: 75, editable: true },
]});

Answer (score 0):

Cross-domain scripting with datatype json in most cases is not allowed with ajax. jqGrid support JSONP, so you will need to set a datatype JSONP instead of JSON.

I highly recommend you to read [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/)